# How to get nearest date?

Tags: c#, linq, date, datetime, min

I have list of dates in a `List`. The user entered date will be compared with the list of dates.

If the list contains that particular date, then the target date will be that date. If the list does not contain that particular date, then the nearest date should be taken as target date.

For that I tried of using `Min` in LINQ:

```
var nearestDiff = getAlldates.Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));
var nearest = getAlldates.Where(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks) == nearestDiff).First();
```

But my `getAlldates` is a list and `targetDate` is string. So I am getting problem here.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Well it seems to me that the first thing you should do is parse `targetDate` to a `DateTime`...

Comment: So your actual problem is converting `targetDate` to `DateTime`? Look at `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact`.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply first parse the `string` to a `DateTime` using [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var nearestDiff = getAlldates
                  .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x)) // this one
                  .Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));
```

Or an improved version, thanks to the input of [Gusdor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/286976/gusdor) and [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen):

```
getAlldates.Min(x => (DateTime.Parse(x) - targetDate).Duration());
```

You might want to specify the date format or the culture to use parsing if the date format isn't the current culture's one. (You might want to use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) for example)

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer `Math.Abs` over `Timespan.Duration`?

Comment: @Gusdor Not that I am aware of. Good suggestion! (I guess it is actually the same)

Comment: The projection in `Select` and the projection in `Min` can be composed (to just one lambda). And using @Gusdor's suggestion, it becomes `getAlldates.Min(x => (DateTime.Parse(x) - targetDate).Duration);`.

Comment: I believe there is a subtle difference in function with the new solution. The first solution will return a `DateTime` as `Enumberable.Min` is called upon an `IEnumerable<DateTime>`. In the second solution, the return value will be the element type of `getAllDates`; `string` I assume. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: You are right on that. Don't know if OP really cares, but I think he has plenty of choice now.

Comment: I would separate into two statements: first convert targetDate to DateTime, since that will need error handling; then obtain the Min. I'm not sure how well LINQ optimizes either - you don't want to parse to a DateTime during every comparison; separating would eliminate that concern.

Comment: @Priya: need more help?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify but I guess list of dates is a list of System.DateTime objects. If your targetDate object is a string, you can't subtract if from a System.DateTime. The part of code you show won't compile:

```
List<System.Datetime> allDates = ...;
string targetDate = ...;
var nearestDiff = getAlldates.Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));
```

To compile it you should convert targetDate into a System.DateTime. If you are certain that the text in targetDate represents a System.DateTime, then you can use System.DateTime.Parse(string) for it, otherwise use TryParse.

The code would loke like:

```
List<System.Datetime> allDates = ...;
string targetDateTxt = ...;
System.DateTime targetDate = System.DateTime.Parse(targetDateText)
System.DateTime nearestDiff = getAlldates.Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));
```

From here the rest of your code works

Comment: Thanks for all your reply :)
Now I changed the data type from string to datetime
Now I'm getting issue in "getAlldates.Min(date => Math.Abs((date - targetDate).Ticks));"

Comment: Now its showing as Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnonymousType#1' and DateTime

Comment: What is the type of your object getAlldates? Does it have an IEnumerable<T> and it T a System.DateTime? Are you sure this object is a IEnumerable<DateTime> and not just an IEnumerable (so a List<DateTime> and not just a List? If you are certain that the elements in your sequence are of type DateTime, Use Enumerable.Cast<DateTime> to make it an IEnumerable<DateTime>. In that case your lambda will be a DateTime. But to be honest, initializing a List<DateTime> is preferable over a List, because you're never sure if everything in the List really is a DateTime

Answer (score 0):

Here's a static method that will return the nearest date.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the nearest date from a range of dates.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dateTime">The target date.</param>
    /// <param name="dateTimes">The range of dates to find the nearest date from.</param>
    /// <returns>The nearest date to the given target date.</returns>
    static DateTime GetNearestDate(DateTime dateTime, params DateTime[] dateTimes)
    {
        return dateTime.Add(dateTimes.Min(d => (d - dateTime).Duration()));
    }
```