# Get nearest dates

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, c#-4.0

```
List<DateTime>

"2015-03-21 13:00:00"
"2015-05-15 13:00:00"
"2015-05-24 13:00:00"
"2015-05-27 13:00:00"
"2015-06-14 13:00:00"
```

I am having *start date* (`2015-05-21 13:00:00`) and *end date* (`2015-06-09 22:00:00`)

Actually I need to get the **two dates** from the above array which are closer or equal to start date and end date.

Note additionally that the date that is closest to the start date should be equal to or before start date and the date that is closest to the end date should be equal to or after the end date. In other words, given the list of dates, find the smallest date range that encloses start and end date.

In this case, the output will be "`2015-05-15 13:00:00`" and "`2015-06-14 13:00:00`".

How to acheive this in c#?

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, tried a lot..

Comment: So please show what you've tried, and explain what went wrong. (As a first idea, sort the list, perform a binary search, and you'll either find a matching date or the index with the adjacent entries...)

Comment: Thanks Jon, Actually it will be more helpful if you post as an answer with just own variable names as `var dates = new List<DateTime>()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31647822/how-to-get-nearest-date?rq=1

Comment: Why is `2015-05-15 13:00:00` closer to `2015-05-21 13:00:00` than `2015-05-24 13:00:00`? What is your definition of *closer*?

Comment: @heijp06, Nice..I forgot the important thing to mention here..Before or equal to start date..Similarly Equal or after to the end date..

Comment: @heijp06 difference in time perhaps, like the number of days/hours between them?

Comment: @Xiaoy312, Time is not much considered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    var dates = new string[]
        {
            "2015-03-21 13:00:00",
            "2015-05-15 13:00:00",
            "2015-05-24 13:00:00",
            "2015-05-27 13:00:00",
            "2015-06-14 13:00:00"
        }
        .Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x))
        .ToList();
        
    var start = DateTime.Parse("2015-05-21 13:00:00");
    var end = DateTime.Parse("2015-06-09 22:00:00");

    Console.WriteLine(dates
        .Where(x => x <= start)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .FirstOrDefault()); 
    Console.WriteLine(dates
        .Where(x => x >= end)
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .FirstOrDefault());
}

// the date must be outside of boundary, so this is no longer good...
//public static DateTime GetClosestDate(IEnumerable<DateTime> source, DateTime date)
//{
//    return source
//        .OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((x.Date - date).TotalSeconds))
//        .First();
//}
```

Result:

> GetClosestDate: 
> 2015-05-24 13:00:00 
> 2015-06-14 13:00:00
>
> Where OrderBy[Descending] FirstOrDefault: 
> 2015-05-15 13:00:00 
> 2015-06-14 13:00:00

Comment: Instead of `List<string>`, can we achieve the solution using `List<DateTime>`

Comment: That is a list of date time, I just went lazy on it.

Comment: If the dates were to be given at compile time and in same format, sure

Comment: Your solution is not working properly. That is, the final output two dates from the list should follow the following rules (__Before or equal to start date..Similarly Equal or after to the end date__). What i need to alter for getting the expected output?

Comment: The latest updated code also not working correcty. It returns __first and last dates__ from the list.

Answer (score 2):

```
public DateTime? GetClosest(List<DateTime> dates, DateTime dateToCompare)
{
    DateTime? closestDate = null;
    int min = int.MaxValue;

    foreach (DateTime date in dates)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(date.Ticks - dateToCompare.Ticks) < min)
        {
            min = date.Ticks - dateToCompare.Ticks;
            closestDate = date;
        }
    }
    return closestDate;
}
```

Simple search on google relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757136/find-the-closest-time-from-a-list-of-times)